# Default Parameter PageSize A4 C# using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, itext, default-parameters

Is it possible to set values for default parameters for PageSize in C#? For example:

```
public virtual void Render(string reportTitle, Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4)
{
    foreach (Page p in pages)
    {
        p.Render(document);
        document.NewPage();
        document.AddCreationDate();
        document.AddTitle(reportTitle);
        document.SetPageSize(pageSize);
    }
}
```

I have the following error in Visual Studio 2010:

> Default parameter value for 'pageSize' must be a compile-time
>   constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write;

```
Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.A4
```

Your `pageSize` value can be change as a parameter.

From [`Named and Optional Arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

The expression `PageSize.A4` is not classified as a *[compile-time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485682/c-what-does-compile-time-const-mean)*.

Comment: Ok Soner, today I was able to change a default parameter for color as follows: public Table(DataTable data, int fontSize = 10, Color fontColor = default(Color))}. I thought I could also do with PageSize. Thanks.