# Breakpoint on const string declaration/initialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Why can't I put a breakpoint on the following line in a private instance method:

```
const string errorMsg = "Test Exeption";
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: You want to see what's going on in [compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485682/what-does-compile-time-const-mean)?

Comment: ahk so it's because that line of code doesn't actually exist in the compiled code. It just instructs the compiler to replace all instances of "errorMsg" with the string "Test Exception".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No IL is emitted for constant declarations, so you will not be able to break on them during debugging.

To add on to that, when a constant is compiled by the C# compiler, the value isn't just passed by reference through a `const` pointer. It's inlined into ever location where the symbol is referenced by your code. Looking at it that way, the code you have declaring the constant isn't really a code location during normal execution at all, and doesn't make sense to attempt to break on.